# Not able to redirect to home page after successful login

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, response.redirect, tomcat5.5, requestdispatcher

**Scenario:** redirecting to home page after successful login using request disaptcher's `include` method.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(uri);    
rd.include(request, response);
```

Where `uri` is the location of the home  page.

In second line, the following exception occurs:

```
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException:Broken pipe
```

So, I tried `response.sendRedirect()` and it worked fine, since I don't know the exact route because of this exception so I thought to pass it.

For this, I caught the exception and tried to redirect to the home page using `response.sendRedirect()` in the `catch` block if this exception occurs. Otherwise, normal `RequestDispatcher`'s `include` will work. **But this, an `IllegalStateException` is occurring.**

I have been trying to find the solution for many days but still no success. Please provide valuable suggestions.

Comment: Why would you want to *redirect* ... with an *include*?

Comment: actually I don't know if there is any specific reason to it. This code has been written earlier by someone else.This issue is reported now and I am debugging it :)

Comment: I see. Well I would say your problem is solved when you change the code to use the correct method. Redirects should always be processed with `redirect`.

Comment: May i know the specific reason of doing this(perform redirects using only response.sendRedirect)

Comment: An include takes the content of the specified resource, and *includes* it as a part of the current resources response. A *redirect* sends the request on to the specified resource to be processed. You *include*, for example, a script or CSS file, but you *redirect* to a login or checkout page.